# Response.Redirect with a subdirectory in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect, subdirectory

I have a little problem with my Redirect in ASP.NET (C#)

I just got a domain which looks like this: `http://www.example.com/subdirectory`

So when I open my asp.net start page, the url looks like this: `http://www.example.com/subdirectory/Startpage/Startpage.aspx`

That's my Redirect in code behind:

```
Response.Redirect("~/UserSite/UserSite.aspx")
```

The problem now is, when I click on that button, I get redirected to

`http://www.example.com/UserSite/UserSite.aspx`

instead of

`http://www.example.com/subdirectory/UserSite/UserSite.aspx`

How can I get my web page to notice the subdirectory in the url?

Would be nice if someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: use this : Response.Redirect("~/subdirectory/UserSite/UserSite.aspx");

Answer (score 2):

This may be because your website under the sub-drecitory hasn't been setup as it's own application within IIS7.

You can do this by:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Open up the website and right click on the sub directory
3. Click on "Convert to Application"
4. You can then change the Application Pool if you wish to have a dedicated one or otherwise just click OK.

Response.Redirect("~/UserSite/UserSite.aspx") should then understand that /subdirectory/ is the default website directory

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. When I rightclick on the whole website I only can choose "Add Application". "Convert" is only for the folders in this website possible. And when I add an application I have this "www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder/UserSite/UserSite.aspx"